# Android: I have to display content from the database in the listview, in which latest data comes on top

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have to implement a listview in which my current data comes on top of the listview. Right now my recent data comes at the bottom and my first data is coming on the top of the listview. I'm attaching my work so far:

SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemClickListener {

private EditText mHistoryNameEditText;
private Button mInsertButton;
private ListView mHistoryListView;

private ListAdapter mHistoryListAdapter;

private ArrayList<SearchHistoryDetails> searchArrayList;

private ArrayList<SearchHistoryDetails> HistoryObjArrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHistoryNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mInsertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mInsertButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mHistoryListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.names_lsitviews);
    mHistoryListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    searchArrayList = new ArrayList<SearchHistoryDetails>();

    mHistoryListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());

    mHistoryListView.setAdapter(mHistoryListAdapter);

    HistoryObjArrayList = new ArrayList<SearchHistoryDetails>();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        String providedUgraduateName = mHistoryNameEditText.getText()
                .toString();

        SearchHistoryDetails undergraduateDetailsPojoObj = new SearchHistoryDetails();
        undergraduateDetailsPojoObj.setuGraduateName(providedUgraduateName);

        HistoryObjArrayList.add(undergraduateDetailsPojoObj);

        insertUndergraduate(undergraduateDetailsPojoObj);

        finish();
    }
}

public void insertUndergraduate(
        SearchHistoryDetails paraUndergraduateDetailsPojoObj) {

    AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(
            this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj
            .getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME,
            paraUndergraduateDetailsPojoObj.getuGraduateName());
    long affectedColumnId = sqliteDatabase.insert(
            AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, contentValues);

    sqliteDatabase.close();
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Values inserted column ID is :" + affectedColumnId,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public List<String> populateList() {

    List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
            AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String ugName = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME));

        SearchHistoryDetails ugPojoClass = new SearchHistoryDetails();
        ugPojoClass.setuGraduateName(ugName);

        searchArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);

        uGraduateNamesList.add(ugName);
    }

    sqliteDatabase.close();

    return uGraduateNamesList;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    searchArrayList = new ArrayList<SearchHistoryDetails>();
    mHistoryListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    mHistoryListView.setAdapter(mHistoryListAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    searchArrayList = new ArrayList<SearchHistoryDetails>();
    mHistoryListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    mHistoryListView.setAdapter(mHistoryListAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on :" + arg2,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    SearchHistoryDetails clickedObject = searchArrayList.get(arg2);

    Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
    dataBundle.putString("clickedUgraduateName",
            clickedObject.getuGraduateName());
}}
```

This class helps me in getting the data from the database and populating it on the activity. My creating database class:

AndroidOpenDbHelper.java

```
public class AndroidOpenDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DB_NAME = "allsearch_history_db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME_GPA = "search_table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME = "undergraduate_name_column";

public AndroidOpenDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sqlQueryToCreateUndergraduateDetailsTable = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_NAME_GPA
            + " ( "
            + BaseColumns._ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME
            + " text not null); ";

    db.execSQL(sqlQueryToCreateUndergraduateDetailsTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2) {
        // Upgrade the database
    }
}}
```

This is the class from which I create database and table.

Now, the real deal is that, when I try to populate data from the database it comes as the first one on top and the latest one on down. I want to revert it. Any help will be appreciated in overcoming this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this. I recommend using the `ORDER BY` clause of your query:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, null, null, null, null, 
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME + " DESC");
```

---

Also if you are only going to read from one column, your query should only request that column. Otherwise you are wasting resources querying unused columns of information:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA,
        new String[] {AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME},
        null, null, null, null, 
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME + " DESC");
```

Lastly, you may want to look into using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) which allows you to bind a query to a ListView with minimal code.

---

**Addition**
I took a closer look at your code and try this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA, null, null, null, null, null, 
        BaseColumns._ID + " DESC");
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer Sam, it is working fine with me. But this query is sorting the data and bringing back in alphabetical manner. Like if I type - "zz" it will be on the top but if I type "aa", "aa" goes down and "zz" comes up. Can you please tell me what is missing here. Here you have DESC which gives the data in descending order. I don't want to do that. Please can you help me regarding this.

Comment: Try removing `"DESC"`. (The opposite of `"DESC"` is `"ASC"`, but `"ASC"` is the default and you don't need to type it.) Otherwise you can try `AndroidOpenDbHelper.ID + " DESC");`.

Comment: Hey Sam, I have tried this but BaseColumn._ID is giving me error, telling me that create a constant in the AndroidOpenDbHelper.class, I tried to do that, but still error is ther. What to do next?

Comment: Thankx Sam, It worked for me. Used ID as the primary key and sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can suggest you to get the data from the database and add the items in the reverse order in the adapter that you are setting for populating the listview.
Consider [this](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html) as the sample where you can get the values from the database which returns an arraylist.
Now consider this arraylist and add each item to the arrayadapter from the last like :

```
for(i=arraylist.size()-1;i>0;i--)
{ 
   adapter.add(arraylist.get(i));
}
```

and after setting for the first time you can call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

to refresh the list automatically.
Give a try to this

Comment: As you have seen I'm getting data using cursor. I have almost spent my whole day in doing this, changing this will not be of much help. I hope you can understand. Is there anything and can bring the data from the database using cursor in reverse order.

Comment: use the primary key column name BaseColumns._ID and  use this
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPA,
        new String[] {AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME},
        null, null, null, null, 
        AndroidOpenDbHelper.BaseColumns._ID + " DESC")

Comment: I have not created BaseColumns field in my DB class, how to do that because I'm getting error on that.

Comment: I am not sure whether i understood it but you have mentioned that in your create table syntax.


String sqlQueryToCreateUndergraduateDetailsTable = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_NAME_GPA
            + " ( "
            + BaseColumns._ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_UNDERGRADUATE_NAME
            + " text not null); ";

Comment: Ya, it is auto-increment. But when I'm accessing BaseColumn._ID from the MainActivity class it is giving me error saying create BaseColumn constant in AndroidOpenDbHelper class. I tried to that in that but then in AndroidOpenDbHelper class giving me error that _ID is not a field. Please see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks Sharath, It worked for me, used ID as the auto-increment removed BaseColumn and sorted by PRIMARY_KEY. +1 for that.

Comment: ok good to hear that.
Can you accept the answer please (If you feel its worthy)

Comment: actually i would love to do that but I have not used that, anyways I have given you +1 for your comment... Cheers !

Comment: cool i said the answer that you felt solved your issue..
not particularly mine. And thanks for +1